# How to write symbol for altered transition matrix?

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to write this in latex:[image: Altered transition matrix label]

Does anyone know how to write this?

(Thanks in advance)

Comment: Mathpix gives `$\widetilde{P}$` as a result. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes! It works thank you! I'll make it an answer. :)

Comment: Oh, nice to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$\widetilde{P}$`

Credit to JairoADelRio

Comment: Hm, this should be written by  @JairoADelRio ...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know.